# Adding a key to the Translation Dataset

Tags: returnn

I have a TranslationDataset and for SelfAttention I want to encode the word boundaries into the Dataset, so I can then use them to limit how far the SelfAttention is allowed to attend. 
I was able to generate a list with boundaries when reading the input into the Dataset, adding the key 'boundaries' to the _data map. The problem is, how can I actually use the data now in my config? Calling data:boundaries in the config does not work (key error boundaries), adding "boundaries":"boundaries" to the KeyMap results in the error Datafile not found boundaries.dev.

Is it possible to call the corresponding boundaries data for each line of the sources in a way that is not used as a "from" input and thus concatenated but rather in a way that allows me to use the data inside the layer to change the energy mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar. I think the only thing you are missing is to add `boundaries` to `targets` in `TranslationDataset._collect_single_seq()`.

Something like:

```
targets = self._get_data(key=self._main_classes_key, line_nr=line_nr)
targets["boundaries"] = self._get_data(key="boundaries", line_nr=line_nr)
```

You will probably also have to add `boundaries` to `num_outputs` (or `extern_data`) in the config.

Referring as `data:boundaries` should work.

I don't get your last question. Every layer can read your data via `"from": "data:boundaries"`, which gives you the data you added in `TranslationDataset` for each training example. Then the layer can use it for anything, in principal. If there are layers doing what you want to do, use them, otherwise implement new ones or use `EvalLayer`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Had to change the DataSeq() in order to also take a boundaries argument but for now it seems like `data:boundaries` actually is callable.
Regarding the second question: 
From my understanding what "From" in the self attention layer does is concatenate the layer inputs and then do the calculations on the concated input. What i want though is actual access to the boundaries and then use them within the attention layer as additional restriction when building the energy mask. Can I also do that via the `"from"` parameter?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of the attention layers. But they inherit from `_ConcatInputLayer`, that's why the layers given via `"from"` are concatenated.

It sounds like you want to add an additional input. This can be done in `transform_config_dict()`. Here, the inputs are converted from names to actual layers. The default behaviour (see `LayerBase`) is that inputs given via "from" are converted into a list of layers called "sources". But you can define other behaviours, in particular add other inputs. For example in `SelfAttentionLayer.transform_config_dict() "key_shift" is added.